# How to know if a card is editable by the current user, using API?

Tags: trello

Hi trello api users and dev team.

We are using client.js to access the trello api.  We are developing board/card lists in grid / edit page for trello api.

Is there a way to know what access rights a user have on a card? When we open our "edit window", we allow a user to edit everything, but when we save a field, if we can't, we receive a "401 not authorized".  How can I know that I can't edit the card before calling the "save" action?

On your native app, if I only have readonly access, the edit window is almost empty, with only the "activity stream".  We would like to do the same.

The results from the /lists or /boards request doesn't seems to contains any property that can tells us if the card is editable for the current user.

Comment: Maybe using the values returned from `/member/id?boards=member`. Then cross check the value sent from `/boards`.

Comment: Almost that, finally I got it from /boards/[boardid]/members
https://trello.com/docs/api/board/index.html#get-1-boards-board-id-members